# I want to run machine learning algorithm using django but django is not taking csv file path

Tags: django, machine-learning, django-views, django-urls

I am creating spam detection system in django in my application from homepage i will enter any string and that string will go to ml function and that function return either string is spam or ham and that result will print on next page but i am not able to define pata of csv file in pd.read_csv function. it is showing error '../data/spam.csv' does not exist: b'../data/spam.csv'

view.py file

```
def hompage(request):
    form = DetectForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def result(request): 
    form=DetectForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        x=form.cleaned_data['msg']
        y=machine(x)
    return render(request, 'result.html',{'msg':y})
```

ml.py file

```
    def machine(stringx):
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        import re
        from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
        from nltk.corpus import stopwords

        data = pd.read_csv('../data/spam.csv', encoding='latin-1')
        data = data.iloc[:, [0, 1]]
        data['v1'] = data.v1.map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})

        courpas = []
        # data_cleaning
        string = stringx
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({"v1": [0],
                            "v2": [string]})
        data = data.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

        # data_cleaning
        for a in data['v2']:
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', a)
            review = review.lower()
            review = review.split()
            ps = PorterStemmer()
            review = [ps.stem(x) for x in review if not x in stopwords.words('english')]
            review = ' '.join(review)
            courpas.append(review)

        # create a bag of word model
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

        cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=5000)
        x = cv.fit_transform(courpas).toarray()
        y = data.iloc[:, 0].values
        x_train, ytrain = x[:-1], y[:-1]
        x_test, y_test = x[5572:5573], y[5572:5573]
        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

        classifier = GaussianNB()
        classifier.fit(x_train, ytrain)
        y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)

        if y_pred == 1:
            return 'spam'

        else:
            return 'ham'
```

result.html file

```
{% block title %}
    <h2>Result</h2>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
        {% endblock %}
```

url.py file

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import  views
    from django.urls import path

    app_name = "spam"
    urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^',views.hompage,name='hompage'),

    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the data folder is the root directory of project then

`data = pd.read_csv('data/spam.csv', encoding='latin-1')` will do the job

or you can create the path using `BASE_DIR` variable using

then use this variable in your views

```
data_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data') # place this in settings.py
```

**in views**

```
from django.conf import settings
data = pd.read_csv(settings.data_dir + 'spam.csv', encoding='latin-1')
```